# Get everything after first character

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get all strings after a the first character?

```
var val = 'asdasd:111122:123123123';
var response = val.substring(val.lastIndexOf(":")+1);

alert(response ); // "123123123"
// Would like: ":111122:123123123"
```

Thank you!

Comment: try `var response = val.substring(val.indexOf(":"));`

Comment: just use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) rather than `lastIndexOf`: `val.substring(val.indexOf(':'))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `indexOf(...)` instead of `lastIndexOf(...)`

If you want to include the `":"` then do not add one to the index.

Like this:

```js
var val = 'asdasd:111122:123123123';
var response = val.substring(val.indexOf(":"));

console.log(response); // ":111122:123123123"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mobileWithCode="+91-9842505145";//mobile value with nation code

mobile = mobileWithCode.substring(mobileWithCode.indexof("-"));

alert(mobile);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Remove +1 And Go ahead your code will work fine

```
var response = val.substring(val.lastIndexOf(":"));

alert(response); // Would Become: ":111122:123123123"
```

Comment: except he does not want the last instance of it  - try it yourself